# Out of memory Error in Google Script when i am trying to get a csv from gmail to spreadsheet which has 50000 rows

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, out-of-memory

I am extracting data from my gmail attachment to google sheet using the below script. But **as the size of data increases** i get "**Out of memory Error**"

I use **G Suite Business / Enterprise**

The csv (in the attachment) goes upto 50,000 rows and 12 columns.

I am using the below script to pull the data from gmail attachment to my google spreadsheet.

```
function TodayRealTime() 
  {
   
 var label = "real time today";

 var thread1=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();

 var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Calcutta', 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z')
  
 for(b=0;b<thread1.length;b++)

 {

   var sheet;
      
   var blob = thread1[b].getMessages().pop().getAttachments();

   if(thread1[b].getFirstMessageSubject()=='Real_Time_Today_hourly 3')
  {
    sheet='gmail_-_Real_time_-_TODAY_15895.csv';
  }
   var Daily_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1MeDYrhkB0b2XT9bXtcOanTUkttI-0zt6OmK7gNKzO8U").getSheetByName('Todayrealtime');

    Daily_sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(date);

   Daily_sheet.getRange('E:L').clearContent();
   
   for (atc=0;atc<blob.length;atc++)
    {

      var data = Utilities.parseCsv(blob[atc].getDataAsString());

      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
     {

        for(j=0;j<data[0].length;j++)

        {

           var val= data[i][j]; 

         Daily_sheet.getRange(i+4,4+1+j).setValue(val);

        }
   
      }
    }
 thread1[b].moveToTrash();
 
 }}
```

Please help as to what can i do to make this script fast or get the data completely.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add the textual error and a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Note: The search [\[goole-apps-script\] out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+Out+of+memory+Error) returns 12 results.

Comment: You know you have limitations? 

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas

Comment: Wow, that's an error one has to try to acheive in GAS :) Joking aside, from a quick glance, you need to do something with N ** 4 (quad?) complexity, especially given the fact that you do I/O operations at the most nested level of looping, regardless of the error

Comment: You really need to cleanup your code and consider using Utilities.parseCsv() to bring in the csv data to the sheet.  I tried going through your but it would be easier to write it myself rather than fixing it up so I gave up.

Answer (score 2):

**Error**

"Out of memory" problem is usually solved by reducing the memory footprint of the program affected. It is hard to tell what *exactly* caused the issue, though, as the feature request to provide info about the offending statement is [yet to be implemented](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754297).

**Optimization points**

1. Move `openById` out of the loop since it is constant
2. Move `getRange(2,1)` out of the loop for the same reason
3. Move `getRange('E:L')` out of the loop for the same reason
4. `clearContent()` only once (I cannot grasp why clear on each iteration)
5. Batch values with `setValues()`
6. Remove `getFirstMessageSubject()` conditional since you do not use `sheet` anyway

What I could not understand is why for each thread you override all data in columns E to L - since `for (atc=0;atc<blob.length;atc++)` is only used to shift data extracted from CSV and all inner loops restart at `0` (and therefore move row and column pointers to `4` and `5` respectively) for each thread. So I left it as is, you will have to figure that one out by yourself.

There are quite a few optimizations that you can apply additionally, for example, I am unsure if you need the inner loop parsing CSV data.

```
function TodayRealTime() {  
  var label = "real time today";
  
  var thread1 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();
  
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Calcutta', 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z');
  dateCell.setValue(date);

  var Daily_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1MeDYrhkB0b2XT9bXtcOanTUkttI-0zt6OmK7gNKzO8U").getSheetByName('Todayrealtime');
  
  var dateCell = Daily_sheet.getRange(2,1);
  var rangeEL  = Daily_sheet.getRange('E:L');
  
  rangeEL.clearContent();
  
  var dataRange = Daily_sheet.getRange(4, 5, data.length, data[0].length);

  thread1.forEach(function (thread) {
      
    var blob = thread.getMessages().pop().getAttachments();
    
    for (atc=0; atc<blob.length; atc++) {
      var data = Utilities.parseCsv(blob[atc].getDataAsString());
      dataRange.setValues(data);
    }
    
    thread.moveToTrash();    
  });
}
```

**Notes**

1. Change your code style to a more conventional for JavaScript - although it is preferential, it is better to keep opening curly brackets for code blocks on the same line as the preceding statement. JavaScript is very eager to assume things for you and even if it did not bite you before, believe me, it will.